# Get string url parameter in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using following htaccess file for my folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?su_id=$1&t=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?su_id=$1&t=$2

</IfModule>
```

When i try to access It is not working

```
www.abc.com/k/?su_id=87&t=this-is-a-google-boy (Original URL)
www.abc.com/k/87/this-is-a-google-boy (try to access url)
```

It is working

```
www.abc.com/k/87/102 (try to access url and it is working)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first url does not comply to your rules

You are asking for 'any letter or number with _ and - included followed by a / and then a number.

`/k/?su_id=xxx` does not have a number after the / but rather a query string. Following the URL you want you need to follwing rule:

`RewriteRule ^([a-Z0-9+-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$     index.php?su_id=$1&t=2  [NC,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

your rule not correct you passing string into number rule, so it wont work

`www.abc.com/k/87/this-is-a-google-boy`

don't fit with the rule

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?su_id=$1&t=$2

try

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?su_id=$1&t=$2
```

it accept /stringornumber/number/stringornumber

```
([0-9]+) accept only number

([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) accept both number & string
```